# ios personal account how to change apple store develoer name

Tags: ios

[image]

My apple account is a personal account and currently the developer name under my app name is my name. I would like to change it to our studio name, is this possible if my account is personal account? and How to do this?

Comment: Have you considered making a business account for your studio and then to transfer the app to the business account?

Comment: Do I need to provide company information or business documents to apple, if I want to use business account? is business account $99?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact Apple Support to change developer name. check this link , [Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/)

Apple's contactsupport :- [How to Contact Us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/)

You can also transfer your app to another account.

> Can I transfer my app to another account?
>
> Yes. Use iTunes Connect to transfer qualifying apps to another account
>   in case of an acquisition, asset purchase, or other similar situation.
>   When you transfer an app, it will remain available on the App Store or
>   Mac App Store, all ratings and reviews will carry over, and users will
>   continue to have access to future updates. To learn more about
>   transferring apps, sign in to iTunes Connect.

Here you will find more detail :-  [changing-app-store-seller-name](http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/)

Comment: can I change the developer name to something like xxx Studio CityName? I am not sure about this as my account is personal account, it is not a business account.

Comment: For changing the name you need to Apple's contact support . you can give name according to your requirement. but you need to contatc apple support.